# Subgroups with trivial Centralizers

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact, simply-connected, and simple Lie group. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ that has the same centralizer as the center of $G$. Is there a nice classification of such subgroups?

**Edit**: Given Misha's example, it seems that classifying such subgroups for all simple groups is hard. So let me pose the following question:

Are there a maximal torus $T$ and $h \in H$ such that $h\in T$ and $h$ is not fixed by any non-trivial element of the Weyl group corresponding to the chosen torus?

Comment: Do you mean: "Is there a closed proper subgroup $H$ such that $C_G(H) = Z(G)$?" (equivalently, $C_G(H) = C_G(G)$)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: $A_5$ in $SU(2)$, assuming you are using the standard notion of simple Lie group.

Comment: @Misha Thanks for your example. I edited my post to two questions which are probably more approachable.

Comment: I guess the second question is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For $G=SU(n)$, the answer is given by Schur's lemma: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ satisfies  $Z_G(H)=Z(G)$ if and only if it acts irreducibly on $\mathbb{C}^n$, that is, if and only if it is not contained in a subgroup $(U(p)\times U(q))\cap SU(n)$. This gives a rather simple criterion.

Comment: Sure! But I don't how to use this classification to answer questions like 1 and 2 above?