# Subgroups with minimal centralizers

Tags: gr.group-theory

Inspired by this question [Subgroups with trivial Centralizers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157444/subgroups-with-trivial-centralizers), one can define a characteristic subgroup in any group $G$ as follows
$$\Lambda(G)=\bigcap\{ H\leq G: C_G(H)=Z(G)\}$$
Is there any description of this subgroup in terms of known group theoretic objects?